# How to use RenderScript with SurfaceView/View

Tags: android, surfaceview, renderscript

Latest Android SDK (R22) has removed `android.renderscript.RSSurfaceView` and `android.renderscript.RenderScriptGL` classes. How can we use RenderScript dirrectly on SurfaceView or regular Android View?

Comment: I would also love to know the answer to this

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: 
It's complicated.

Long answer:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder

They seem to make an RGBA allocation:

```
    Type.Builder rgbTypeBuilder = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs));
    rgbTypeBuilder.setX(dimensions.getWidth());
    rgbTypeBuilder.setY(dimensions.getHeight());
    mOutputAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbTypeBuilder.create(),
            Allocation.USAGE_IO_OUTPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
```

Then get a surface from a SurfaceView holder to pass to the allocation. Then they run some rs on it, and then call:

```
mOutputAllocation.ioSend();
```

for each frame...
Check the code, seems there are some pitfalls there.